# xquery order by with results from fn replace

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-3.0

I'm ordering search results (from many XML files) according to the contents of the XML element . Tricky thing is I need to order the results according to only a part of the string found in this element, namely the number following the string 'Rep.'. For instance 'BPH, Rep. **49**, T I Nr. 22' should come before 'I. HA Rep. **100**, Nr. 2233'. I use regex to isolate the substring with fn:replace. The regex is definitely correct, it spits out the right number every time. For some reason it won't order correctly though. What am I missing? Thanks from a newbie.

The XML looks like this:

```
<xml>
<idno>I. HA Rep. 100, Nr. 2233</idno>
<idno>I. HA Rep. 100, Nr. 2535</idno>
<idno>BPH, Rep. 113, Nr. 1694</idno>
<idno>BPH, Rep. 113, Nr. 2845</idno>
<idno>BPH, Rep. 192 NL Wittgenstein, IV, 2, 14</idno>
<idno>BPH, Rep. 49, T I Nr. 21</idno>
<idno>BPH, Rep. 49, T I Nr. 22</idno>
<idno>(D) BPH, Rep. 48, Nr. 141</idno>
<idno>(D) BPH, Rep. 48, Nr. 144</idno>
<idno>BPH, Rep. 192, NL Wittgenstein, VI,9,7</idno>
<idno>I. HA Rep. 178 F, Nr. 31</idno>
</xml>
```

Xquery is like this:

```
  for $record in $records
  order by replace($record//idno, '(.*Rep\.\s)(\d+)(.*)', '$2')
  return $record//idno
```

The result:

```
I. HA Rep. 100, Nr. 2233
I. HA Rep. 100, Nr. 2535 
BPH, Rep. 113, Nr. 2845 
BPH, Rep. 113, Nr. 1694 
I. HA Rep. 178 F, Nr. 31 
BPH, Rep. 192, NL Wittgenstein, VI,9,7 
BPH, Rep. 192 NL Wittgenstein, IV, 2, 14 
(D) BPH, Rep. 48, Nr. 141 
(D) BPH, Rep. 48, Nr. 144 
BPH, Rep. 49, T I Nr. 21 
BPH, Rep. 49, T I Nr. 22
```

Desired result:

```
(D) BPH, Rep. 48, Nr. 141
(D) BPH, Rep. 48, Nr. 144
BPH, Rep. 49, T I Nr. 21
BPH, Rep. 49, T I Nr. 22
I. HA Rep. 100, Nr. 2233
I. HA Rep. 100, Nr. 2535
BPH, Rep. 113, Nr. 1694
BPH, Rep. 113, Nr. 2845
I. HA Rep. 178 F, Nr. 31
BPH, Rep. 192, NL Wittgenstein, VI,9,7
BPH, Rep. 192 NL Wittgenstein, IV, 2, 14
```

If I change my 'order by' to something simple - like, ordering by a different element without using regex - it works. I can't figure out how it is ordering. We are talking about thousands of idnos, and I can't figure out the pattern it is supposedly ordering them by. I can add more  to the list though if someone needs more examples to figure it out. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to test using your input and sample XQuery, but try wrapping `replace()` in `number()`...

```
order by number(replace($record, '(.*Rep\.\s)(\d+)(.*)', '$2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If $records is a sequence of `<idno>` elements, then $record is an `<idno>` element and $record//idno will select nothing; you should just reference `$record`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sorry, I didn't mention that the XML is actually complexer, I simplified it for the example here and removed all the parent elements, etc., except 'idno'. Daniel Haley caught the mistake - the result of fn:replace is a string, so I need fn:number so that 'order by' knows to order the result like a number (if i understood it correctly).